# MySQL ORDER BY > swap results if values are equal

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm using a simple MySQL statement to query my DB for product suggestions sorted by clicks:

```
SELECT * FROM suggestions WHERE source = :source_item_id ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 7
```

It all works as expected. However, if the clicks are the same, is there a way to tell MySQL to spit them out randomly?

Example:

```
Product  Clicks
1        2
2        2
3        3
```

If queried, the order is 3, 2, 1 and it will always be this order if clicks don't change. How can I randomize product 1 and 2 that have w clicks each? Every now and then I want to swap the result, i.e. make it 3, 1, 2 and maybe next time 3, 2, 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding a column with a random value and having a secondary sort on it?

```
SELECT product, clicks, RAND() AS rand 
FROM suggestions 
WHERE source = :source_item_id 
ORDER BY clicks, rand 
DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not...

```
SELECT product, clicks
FROM suggestions 
WHERE source = :source_item_id 
ORDER BY clicks DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 7
```

...?